# Write an equation of a circle that passes through the point $(s,3s)$ centered at $(a,b)$.

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles

Find the equatio of circle that passes through the point $(s,3s)$ centered at $(a,b)$.
I don't know what to do when the point has variables. Should I replace it with numerical values?

Comment: It shouldn't be any different than when it has numerical values. Identify the center; plug that into the relevant bits of the equation. Calculate the radius; plug that into the relevant bit of the equation. Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Computing the radius is easy enough. What would be the equation of such a circle if it was centered at $(0,0)$?  And how does the equation transform when you shift the circle to its place?

Answer (score 0):

Given Center $C = (a, b)$ and Circle passes through point say$(P)$ $P = (s, 3s)$

Equation Form : $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = R^2$

The radius of circle$(R^2)$ = $(s-a)^2 + (3s-b)^2$ As you know the point $P $ and center $C$

Thus,

$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = (s-a)^2+(3s-b)^2 = R^2$   is your equation for the circle.